# Cannot get Hover to effect 2 elements on different levels of same position

Tags: html, css, hover, rows

I'm trying to recreate a copy of a website I found interesting. I have a table of div set up, in rows. Over the rows I have set up 4 divs with absolute positioning in the shape of columns and set the display to none. When I hover over a element in the row I would like both the row's hover effect to activate and the column effect to activate for the whole column. I've tried selecting for element in the column position .one .two etc and selecting for the column row.one:hover ~ #col, however everything I've tried only seems to activate the top level element not both at once(these element are overlapping in places. Would really appreciate any help fixing this. I would like to be able to do this effect without javascript.

```
https://jsfiddle.net/peacefulgoldfish/txcet4yw/2/
```

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow: hidden;
}

h1,
h2 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

#container {
  width: 80vw;
  margin: auto;
  height: auto;
  background-color: rgb(123, 108, 160);
  position: relative;
}

.row {
  height: 125px;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.one {
  border: none;
  height: 125px;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0px;
}

.two {
  border: none;
  height: 125px;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 0px;
}

.three {
  border: none;
  height: 125px;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: white;
}

.four {
  border: none;
  height: 125px;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: green;
}

.row:hover>div {
  background-color: red;
}

#col1 {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: purple;
  float: left;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: .7;
  mix-blend-mode: hardlight;
}

.row.one:hover~#col {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<h1>WEB</h1>
<h2>Hey everyone</h2>
<div id="header"> </div>
<div id="container">
  <!-- column selectors -->
  <div id="col1"></div>
  <div id="col2"></div>
  <div id="col3"></div>
  <div id="col4"></div>


  <div class="row">
    <div class="one">
      <p>Week 1</br> May 7 <br> - <br> May 11 </p>
    </div>
    <div class="two">
      <ul>
        <li> Course introduction </li>
        <li> Internet Architecture </li>
        <li> Introduction to Javascript </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="three">
      <a href=""> Welcome </a>
      <a href="">Lecture 1 </a>
    </div>

    <div class="four">
      <h3> Work Due </h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="one">
      <p> Week 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="two">
      <ul>
        <li> Javascript functions </li>
        <li> Built in Global Functions </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="three">
      <a href=""> Lecture 2 </a>
    </div>
    <div class="four"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="one"></div>
    <div class="two"></div>
    <div class="three"></div>
    <div class="four"></div>

  </div>
</div>


<div class="special"></div>
```

[image: display on column set to none]
[image: display on col1 set to block, mouse is hovering over col1, and it's also blocking row1 hover effect]

Comment: Can you give a link of that website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understand you right so it is a solution for you

css:

```
    body {
        width: 100vw;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        background-color:blue;
        overflow:hidden;

    }
    h1, h2{
        font-family: sans-serif;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
    }


    #container {
        width:  80vw;
        margin: auto;
        height: auto;
        background-color:rgb(123,108,160);
        position: relative;


    }
    .row{
        height: 125px;
        background-color:green;

        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;

    }

    .col-trigger{
        border: none;
        height: 125px;
        float: left;
        width: 25%;
        margin: 0px;
    }

    .white{
        background-color:white;

    }

    .green{
        border-color: green;
    }

    .row:hover > div{

        background-color:red;
    }

    .col{
        position: absolute;
        height:100%;
        width: 25%;
        display: none;
        background-color: purple;
        float:left;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 1;
        opacity: .7;
        mix-blend-mode: hardlight;
        pointer-events: none;
    }

    .col2 {

        left: 25%;

    }
    .col3 {

        left: 50%;

    }
    .col4 {

        left: 75%;

    }

    .col-trigger:hover+.col{
        display: block;
     }
```

html:

```
    <h1>WEB<h1>
    <h2>Hey everyone</h2>
    <div id="header"> </div>
    <div id="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-trigger white">
            <p>Week 1</br> May 7 <br> - <br> May 11 </p>

        </div>
        <div class="col col1"></div>

        <div class="col-trigger green">
            <ul>
                <li> Course introduction </li>
                <li> Internet Architecture </li>
                <li> Introduction to Javascript </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col col2"></div>

        <div class="col-trigger white">
            <a href=""> Welcome </a>
            <a href="" >Lecture 1 </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col col3"></div>


        <div class="col-trigger green">
            <h3> Work Due </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col col4"></div>

    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-trigger white"><p> Week 2</p></div>
        <div class="col col1"></div>

        <div class="col-trigger green">
            <ul>
                <li> Javascript functions </li>
                <li> Built in Global Functions </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col col2"></div>

        <div class="col-trigger white">
            <a href=""> Lecture 2 </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col col3"></div>

        <div class="col-trigger green"></div>
        <div class="col col4"></div>

    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-trigger white"></div>
        <div class="col col1"></div>
        <div class="col-trigger green"></div>
        <div class="col col2"></div>
        <div class="col-trigger white"></div>
        <div class="col col3"></div>

        <div class="col-trigger green"></div>
        <div class="col col4"></div>



    </div>
    </div>


    <div class="special"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was trying to do

Comment: theres a few things I don;t understand about your answer, for example why do the columns take the background-color of the rows no matter wwhat background color I specify.

Comment: because the background color of  `.row:hover>div` override the background color of `.col`. if you want the columns in another color add the `background-color` property in the `.color-trigger:hover+.col`